# Metamask Chrome extension can't send deployed ERC721?

Tags: tokens, metamask, erc-721, nft

I deployed an ERC721 token on bsc testnet, added it to Metamask Chrome extension. It shows up correctly, but the button "send" is faded out. Am I missing something?

Comment: Screenshots and details please

Answer (score 0):

Metamask doesn't seem to support NFT transfers, haven't you noticed that when you use it to transfer money, it doesn't specify a tokenId at all?

Comment: I can see that. Hopefully they will implement supporting NFT transfers since it's becoming such a popular protocol.